# Convert PHP site to Ajax-driven site

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

After weeks of failure, I am completely lost as to how I can covert my site to be ajax based. The main purpose is that I have a bar at the bottom that plays music and I would like it to play as the pages change. Please help me figure this out!

**The Ajax area includes:**

- Google AdSense and Adbrite ads (although I can go without these in Ajax area)
- Several jQuery plugins and javascript functions (NEED these to work in Ajax area)
- Normal links so that non javascript users can still browse + for SEO purposes (so links need to look like "/Link/Page/1/"
- ALL content is grabbed used php switch statements and $_GET

**What I've Tried:**

- jQuery History Plugin
- Asual Address Plugin
- http://www.malbecmedia.com/blog/development/coding-a-ajax-site-that-degrades-gracefully-with-jquery/
- jQuery ajax calls (jQuery.ajax)

That's the majority of the situation, minus some small details, I am definitely not going to use frames and would really like to figure something out. Also note that the ajax area contain links that change the music, so everything needs to correspond together.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What doesn't work?

Comment: Well the link I attached works well to change the ajax area, but I am unable to get history to work AND any javascript I need inside the area does not work.

Comment: Sorry, but your question pretty much sounds like "How do I build a website?" You need to be much more specific. I don't think anyone here is willing to give a complete beginners course to web development.

Comment: I am far from needing a full how to build a website speech, just looking for ideas based on what the ajax area requires..

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is to look into using the `<div>` tag with the "innerHtml" attribute.  You can also use `<iframe>` to accomplish what you are looking to do.  The `<iframe>` would link to your other page.

For "real" AJAX, use xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); instead.  This will make calls to your other pages, and your other pages will respond without sending all of the additional coding information.  It is basically the same idea as loading iframes without all of the overhead.

Take a look at this page for a simple idea:

http://www.sipen.com/viewproduct.php?id=37

As you click on each of the images to the right, the big image changes.  This is basically Ajax in its simplest form.  You can also use the following for an easy solution:

```
  <script language="javascript">
  function setRPS (rps)
  {
    document.getElementById('rpschoice').value = rps;
    document.forms[0].submit();
  }

  function countdown(timerValue)
  {
    if (timerValue < 16)
    {
      document.getElementById('countdown').style.color = '#FF0000';
    }
    if (timerValue < 6 && timerValue > -1)
    {
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Auto-selecting in " + timerValue.toStrin
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = timerValue.toString();
    }
    if (timerValue < 0)
    {
      timerValue = 0;
      setRPS("auto");
    }
    else
    {
      setTimeout("countdown(" + timerValue + "- 1)", 1000);
    }
  }
</script>
```

To make life easier, though, you can simply use JQuery with `$.ajax()`.

Comment: please, use <script type="text/javascript">. it's 2010.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this a little more, but I am using jQuery and php, and I am using ajax in parts of my site without problems. My main problem is getting already loaded javascript to work inside the ajax area after a call is made, so I will look into new xmlhttprequest more, to see if that helps.